# Javascript Floating Number Comparison

Tags: javascript, floating-point, comparison

I'm trying to do what I thought was pretty straight forward but having odd results.  I have two fields on a page:  `transactionAmount` and `transactionLimit`.  When the button is clicked, it calls a javascript function that makes sure the amount isn't greater than the limit:

```
var transactionAmount = parseFloat(document.getElementById("amount").value).toFixed(2);
var transactionLimit = parseFloat(document.getElementById("limit").value).toFixed(2);

if (transactionAmount > transactionLimit) {
  alert("Over limit");
}
```

If I set the transactionAmount to be $2.00 and the transaction Limit to be $100.00, I get the over limit alert.  If I set the transactionAmount to be $1.00 then it works fine.  Basically any other value less than $1.00 works if the limit is $100.00 but anything over $1.00 gives me the error.

Would be grateful for some insight!  Thank you!

Comment: You're comparing _strings_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem happening because of `toFixed(2)` it converts your result to `string` that's why your condition is not working as you expected. just wrap it with preceding `+` character to make it **Number** from **String**

```js
var transactionAmount = +(parseFloat('2.00').toFixed(2));
var transactionLimit = +(parseFloat('100.00').toFixed(2));
console.log(transactionAmount,transactionLimit, typeof transactionAmount,typeof transactionLimit )
if (transactionAmount > transactionAmount ) {
  console.log("Over limit");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the function "Number()" to you values, toFixed() actually transform them to string. You can also add a "+" before to do the same action.

Example:

```
    var transactionAmount = Number(parseFloat("150.00").toFixed(2)); //or: +parseFloat("150.00").toFixed(2)
    var transactionLimit = Number(parseFloat("100.0").toFixed(2)); //or: +parseFloat("100.0").toFixed(2)

    if (transactionAmount > transactionLimit)
    {
       alert("Over limit");
    } else {
        alert("you ok dude");
    }
```

Output:

```
"Over limit"
```

I hope it helps you!

Comment: Thank you - I appreciate it!!